# Checkout a remote branch without tracking it

Tags: git, gitpython

I have forked a project in Gitlab to my own namespace. I want to create a new branch of that project that mirrors the original repo's master but I do not want to set a remote in my forked repo nor do I want to track that branch. Is there any way I can do it?

Answer (score 3):

`git checkout -b my_branch --no-track <remote>/master`